# Likelihood ratio for the mean ($\theta$) of an independent identically distributed sample normally distributed with known variance $\sigma= 1$

Tags: statistics

In a statistical hypothesis testing, the initial hypothesis is $\theta\ge0$ and the alternative hypothesis is $\theta<0$. I'm asked to find the likelihood ratio $\Gamma(x)$ for a given test size $\alpha$.

Edit: I've found a maximum likelihood estimator for the mean by the method of the moments which would be the arithmetic mean $\bar x$.

Comment: If you found an estimator by the method of moments, that doesn't show that it's the maximum-likelihood estimator.  The method of moments and the method of maximum likelihood are two different things.

Comment: So, if i use the method of moments i still have to find the likelihood functions maximum for the parameter space both in the initial hypothesis (numerator in the likelihood ratio given by the maximum likelihood method) and the whole space for the denominator? I tried to use the $ \[ \frac{\partial \sum_1^n{\log(f(x(i))}}{\partial \theta} = 0]$ roots, but the derivatives were 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The likelihood is
$$
L(\theta) = \exp\left( \frac{-n(\bar X-\theta)^2} 2 \right).
$$
The value of $\theta\in\mathbb R$ that maximizes this is $\hat\theta_1= \bar X$. The value of $\theta\in[0,\infty)$ that maximizes this is
$$
\hat\theta_0
=\begin{cases}
\bar X & \text{if }\bar X\ge 0, \\
0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
So the likelihood ratio is
$$
\frac{L(\hat\theta_1)}{L(\hat\theta_0)} =
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if }\bar X\ge0, \\[8pt]
\dfrac{\exp(-n/2)}{\exp(-n\bar X^2/2)} & \text{if }\bar X<0.
\end{cases}
$$
The second piece is an increasing function of $\dfrac{-n}2\left( 1-\dfrac{\bar X} 2 \right)$; hence a decreasing function of $\bar X$.

Thus the likelihood ratio remains constant as $\bar X$ varies within $[0,\infty)$ and increases as $\bar X$ moves away from $0$ in the other direction.

Now think about the distribution of $\bar X$ to find the critical value for each value of $\alpha$.

Comment: $\bar x$ follows a normal distribution of mean $\theta$ and variance $1/\sqrt{n}$. But, test size is the supremum of the probability of the critical region for the initial hypothesis. How can i express it in terms of the likelihood ratio?

Comment: The probability of the critical region is maximized by taking $\theta=0$,  If you know the critical region, can you find its probability given that $\theta=0$?

Comment: I don't know how to express the critical region to calculate his probability.

Comment: My answer should explain why the critical region is $\bar X<c$ for some negative number $c$.  You need $\Pr(\bar X<c) = \alpha$, so $\Pr(\sqrt n \, \bar X < c\sqrt n)=\alpha$, and thus $\Pr(Z < c\sqrt n)=\alpha$.  Thus $c\sqrt n = \Phi^{-1}(\alpha)$.  That tells you what $c$ is. ${}\qquad{}$